# Would questions about a piece of gaming-related software be classified as 'off topic'?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

Say person A has a question. He has a piece of software, related to gaming, that is not functioning as expected. Is he able to ask for help on this problem?

Comment: what is the actual software he is using?

Comment: Hey Again! We keep meeting like this. Anyway, you guessed it, its x360ce. BUT: this time I have got it working, I just want the Vibration.

Comment: 'Software related to gaming', or, as out FAQ refers to it, 'game-specific hardware and utilities' is somewhat nebulous, but in general, a common sense reading will tell you whether it fits here. Questions about Steam, for example, are commonplace and a perfect fit. Questions about using Photoshop to clean up your screenshots, less so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It says on [this Help Center page](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), that:

> If your question generally covers things such as … Game-specific hardware and utilities …then you are in the right place to ask your question!

So, I believe so, as long as your question doesn't also match any of the prohibited question criteria also on that page.